# Windows service stop automatically

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, windows-services

I want to call a stored procedure from windows service and after that I want to self stop the service.  Here is what I have:

```
public DailyChecker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ChangeState", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I start the service, it stops automatically at instance and shows a message box.

Comment: aside from the fact that I don't know why you need a windows-service in this case I cannot really see why the service should stop - but I guess the account the service is running has some access-right problems with your database ... have you tried looking in the windows-eventlogs and what does the messagebox tell you?

Comment: You are right there is an access problem. I'll deal with that. Thanx

Comment: I have change the serviceProcessInstaller's property Account to LocalSystem. Now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the serviceProcessInstaller's property Account to LocalSystem. Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand your appraoch, but this should simply be a case of calling  base.OnStop

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ChangeState", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
base.OnStop();
```

Comment: Try adding a catch block after the try and tracing the error. It could be that your SP call is failing and crashing the service

Comment: I have change the serviceProcessInstaller's property Account to LocalSystem. Now it's working